Circular Permutations of Repeated Objects with Restraints

Bob wants to use 8 indistinguishable black beads and 32 indistinguishable white beads to make a necklace such that there are at least 2 white beads between any 2 black beads. In how many ways can this be done?

My approach so far is to initially create 8 blocks of “BWW”. Now, place the remaining 16 white beads between each block. This becomes equivalent to finding the number of circular permutations of 8-partitions of the integer 16.
For example, for the partition 9+1+1+1+1+1+1+1, there is 1 circular permutation. For the partition 2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2, there is also 1 circular permutation and so on.
I am not sure how to calculate this. I have written code to verify this procedure and received the correct answer of 30667.
However, this problem is from the second chapter of a combinatorics book, so concepts such as Polya enumeration and generating functions are not introduced yet (I also have not learned Polya yet).
Could anyone please shed some light on an elementary approach to this problem?

I prefer the method of problem solving where you continually notice and note precise properties of the situation until an obvious answer falls out. This is intuitively "why" you created your 8 blocks of BWW. The solutions have to look like (any amount of W) concatenated with any amount of (BWW followed by any amount of W's). So in total you are spending 32 W's and 8 B's. So you already know how to place 16 of those W's. Now have you noticed enough to write the solution precisely?

HINT 2: For each of the remaining 16 W's you can place it in one of 9 spots.

oh I realize the whole point of your question is that it is modular rotating the beads around your neck, so there are no endpoints. Well that changes what I wrote obviously so ignore that

Where did you encounter this problem?  Please credit the original source.  Rather than saying it is from a book, please list the book title, authors, and the chapter/section/exercise number.  Note that we have a policy requiring you to provide attribution for all material originally written by others: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing
